# Computer turns on and off very quickly, then nothing, then works?

Tags: power-supply, computer-building

The strange nature of this problem is what is stumping me. I built my computer about 7 months ago using all new parts off of Newegg (not a kit or anything).

One day, I wake up and turn on my computer. I press the power button and it turns on, but then back off after half a second.

I press the power button again, this time nothing. I continue pressing the power button while at the same time turning the power supply on and off (to try and reset things). The power button still does nothing.

But then, after about 5 minutes - voilà! It works just fine like nothing was ever wrong.

It goes for an entire week working just fine. Then, one morning, the entire process starts again. I press the power button and it comes on and then right back off. I press the power button several times and nothing happens, and then it works again after a couple minutes of trying.

What is going on with my computer?

Comment: So it was a faulty motherboard? Did they ever find a solution?

Comment: Did your problem happen all at once or just once a week-ish like mine?

Comment: hahahaha i like your spelling of Voila better hahaha

Comment: Also, my two cents: I, too, had a huge problem that occurred extremely rarely where my computer would randomly (read: too unregularly to cause it to fail) freeze and I had difficulty troubleshooting. The only reliable recourse in this situation is to bite the bullet and temporarily invest in parts for suspected components, and return them if not needed. FWIW, my m4 SSD had a firmware bug that caused it to fail about once an hour after 5200 hours. Otherwise it worked fine. tough to even google that kind of symptom :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also didn't say whether or not the computer was custom built with all new parts or, perhaps, some were scavenged from other computers.

Try the following -

- double-check that all of your wires are connected properly (including the wires leading to the switch)
- check to make sure that you don't have an accumulation of dust or other debris (carefully blow it out with a can of compressed air if you)
- check the power supply by transferring it to another computer that is known to be working
- install a **new** power supply appropriate for the other components

This isn't an exhaustive list; just things I've encountered over the years building my own systems.

If nothing suggested here works, take it to a local computer repair shop.

(Edited to reflect updates to the question.)

Comment: read the question again... It was clearly edited to say he built it himself

Comment: When I started typing, it didn't.

Comment: I know Im letting you know that he edited it

Comment: Thanks for giving me a simple checklist of things to try. The next time it happens (and it will), I will try some of these things. The rarity of the issue makes it difficult to troubleshoot though....

Comment: @hellohellosharp The term is "intermittent"

Answer (score -5):

Try changing the power supply.

Try changing components. Power supply.
That power supply in another machine.  Another power supply in your machine.

It's going to be either your power supply is bad or not plugged in right, or your motherboard is bad. So if you prove it's not the power supply, then process of elimination, it's the motherboard. But i'd think it's the power supply if anything. I am not sure how a bad motherboard could behave like that though maybe it could. You'd see if you bothered to do some troubleshooting.

Comment: I DID build the computer actually, sorry I guess the term "Custom-built" is slightly misleading. I have access to the interior. I tried switching some things around but nothing seemed to show the problem. I wasn't sure if my power supply was stable so I did not want to touch the wrong thing.

Comment: @hellohellosharp  it's safe to remove a power supply unit(PSU). A PSU is (also?), an ACDC adaptor.All the low voltage/current DC on the outside is fine+covered.The danger is opening up the PSU itself and touching it while it is on.There might(i'm not sure) be a danger in opening a power supply with no power on but getting zapped by charge in a capacitor.But i'm just talking about removing the power supply, not taking the power supply itself apart.You won't harm anything by removing the PSU.There's no danger.This stable/unstable thing in your mind is nonsense you might've thought of in a dream.

Comment: Okay, next time it happens I will try removing the power supply. What about the Front Panel Connections? Is it possible that my case has a loose connection with the mobo?

Comment: @hellohellosharp front panel connections wouldn't be my first suspicion, but it is very mysterious. If you swap the PSU and find it doesn't help, then look at the front panel connections.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6712/discussion-between-barlop-and-malwaremaniac)